# com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: myrequest returned a response status of 404 Not Found

Tags: ajax, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey, http-status-code-404

**myrequest**

`POST http://someIPA:PORT/MyWARFILENAME/backend/Activation/Request`

I am getting a 404 for a REST api call. This is the first time I am trying to run this. I know I am missing something really basic here.

**Web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mycompany.backend.webservices</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webservices/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Service Code**

```
package com.mycompany.backend.webservices;
@Path("/Activation")
public class Activation {

    @POST
    @Path("Request")
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public Response post(JAXBElement<CDeviceDetails> data) {
        // Do my thing, set everything_is_ok to true/false
        if (everything_is_ok)
            return Response.ok(everthing).build();
        else
            return Response.notModified().build();
    }
}
```

**junit test code**

```
    //
    // Activation Service
    //
    URI url = UriBuilder.fromUri(
            "http://" + SERVER + "/MyWARFILENAME/backend/Activation/Request")
            .build();
    WebResource service = client.resource(url);
    System.out.println(url);
    // Get the data ready
    CDeviceDetails newDevice = new CDeviceDetails(null, "mac id", "model",
            "manufacturer", "androidVersion", Calendar.getInstance()
                    .getTime(), "buildID", "fingerPrint", "board",
            "bootLoader", "hardware", "id", "product", "serial", Calendar
                    .getInstance().getTime(), Calendar.getInstance()
                    .getTime(), Globals.ACTIVE);
    String deviceUniqueIdentity = service.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .post(String.class, newDevice);
    assertNotNull(deviceUniqueIdentity);
    System.out.println("Activation Passed " + deviceUniqueIdentity);
```

**Server side log /var/log/tomcat7/localhost_access_log.2014-09-28.txt**

> IPA - - [TIMESTAMP] "POST /MyWARFILENAME/backend/Activation/Request HTTP/1.1" 404 1049

Which means that the request is reaching the server. Even if in **//Do my thing..** there is a exception, it should not matter, and I should not get a `404`.

I suspect something fishy on the web.xml.

Comment: I don't use jersey but I would imagine the url pattern `/webservices/*` should be used as the root. So you may want to try and replace `backend` with `webservices` in the path you are trying to access. [**`404`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) means the resource could not be found, which would be correct in your case, if the uri path is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

I modified by web.xml mapping from `webservices` to `backend` and it started to work.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/backend/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```